# Send & receive data simultaneously over Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

Can I use Bluetooth to send and receive data at the same time and make a full-duplex connection between two devices?  I'm trying to connect an Android device and an Arduino (or AVR micro), and send data between them simultaneously (in real time).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see
Bluetooth Chat 
developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
Thank's everyone for help